# How to to add "th" or "rd" to the date

Tags: lua

What I wanted to do is to add "th" or "rd" to the date, i.e 27th, 30rd etc in Lua.

I'm sure it's best to use loop to accomplish this task, Is it possible?

I tried browsing/learn and try for myself but I failed over and over.

**MeasureDate** and **MeterDate** is the one for adding Date.

I've pasted the code below.

```
;----------RainMeter

[Rainmeter]
Update=#UpdateRateAmount#



;-------- Lua Script
[LuaScript]
Measure=Script
ScriptFile=#skinspath#/MyScript.lua


;---------Variables

[Variables]
@include="#skinspath#/SkinVariables.inc"

[ClockStyle]
FontFace=#Font#
FontColor=#ClockFontColor#
AntiAlias=1
FontSize=120
StringAlign=Left
StringEffect=Border
FontEffectColor=#ClockFontEffectColor#

;---- Minute Variables

[MinuteStyle]
FontFace=#Font#
FontColor=#MinuteFontColor#
AntiAlias=1
FontSize=120
StringAlign=Left
StringEffect=Border
FontEffectColor=#MinuteFontEffectColor#


[FontStyle]
FontFace=#Font#
FontColor=#FontColor#
AntiAlias=1
StringAlign=Left
StringEffect=Border
FontEffectColor=#FontEffectColor#


;--------Date


;---------Clock
[MeasureDate]
Measure=Time
Format=%d 
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#

[MeasureHour]
Measure=Time
Format=%#ClockMode#
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#

[MeasureMinute]
Measure=Time
Format=%M
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#

[MeasureWeekday]
Measure=Time
Format=%A
Substitute="Sunday":"SUN","Monday":"MON","Tuesday":"TUES","Wednesday":"WED","Thursday":"THURS","Friday":"FRI","Saturday":"SAT"
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#


[MeasureMonth]
Measure=Time
Format=%b
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#
StringCase=Upper
Substitute="Jan":"JAN.","Feb":"FEB.","Mar":"MAR.","Apr":"APR.","Jun":"JUN.","Jul":"JUL.","Aug":"AUG.","Sep":"SEP.","Oct":"OCT.","Nov":"NOV.","Dec":"DEC."
FontFace=Courier

[MeasureYear]
Measure=Time
Format=%Y
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#

[I]
Measure=Time
Format=%p
UpdateDivider=#UpdateDividerAmount#

[MeterHour]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureHour
MeterStyle=ClockStyle
X=9r
Y=-9r
Text='%1'

[BetweenMinHr]
Meter=String
FontSize=45
MeterStyle=MinuteStyle
Text=:
x=200r
y=60r

[MeterMinute]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureMinute
MeterStyle=MinuteStyle
X=0r
Y=-63r
Text='%1'


[MeterWeekday]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureWeekday
MeterStyle=FontStyle
StringAlign=Right
FontSize=30
StringCase=Upper
X=16r
Y=153r
Text='%1'

[MeterDate]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureDate
MeterStyle=FontStyle
StringAlign=Center
FontSize=120
X=70r
Y=-10r
StringEffect=BORDER
Text='%1'


[MeterMonth]
Meter=String
MeasureName=MeasureMonth
MeterStyle=FontStyle
StringAlign=Left
FontSize=40
X=-200r
Y=43r
Text='%1'

[MeterAm/Pm]
Meter=String
MeasureName=#ClockMode#
MeterStyle=FontStyle
StringAlign=Left
FontSize=35
X=310r
Y=-75r

[MeterBox]
Meter=Image
SolidColor=2,1,1,0
X=-380r
Y=-240r
H=280
W=450
```

**SkinVariables.inc**

> [Variables]
>
> ```
> Font=Century Gothic
>
> ;---- Clock
> ;For a 12 hour clock mode, put 'I'
> ;For a 24 hour clock mode, put 'H'
> ClockMode=I
>
> FontColor=35,35,35,255
> FontEffectColor=255,255,255,150
> ClockFontColor=35,35,35,255
> ClockFontEffectColor=242,242,242,100
>
> MinuteFontColor=255,255,255,255
> MinuteEffectColor=0,0,0,128
> MinuteFontEffectColor=0,0,0,128
> ```

Comment: Where did you get the notion that this was Lua? Are you sure you're using the right language? Regardless, try searching for "ordinal number conversion" in the proper language.

Comment: Oh wow, I mean, I need a help to develop a lua script to accomplish what I wanted to do. (My bad)

Comment: You'll probably want to edit your post then to state that you want to convert that to Lua.

Comment: I just recently edited to notify that I wanted it to be converted to LUA language.

Comment: FYI: The language is called *Lua* not LUA and the correct English ordinal suffix of 30 is "th". Also there is nothing to convert, it's just a bunch of config lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily accomplish changing numbers into ordinal numbers with the following function:

```
function ordinal_numbers(n)
  local ordinal, digit = {"st", "nd", "rd"}, string.sub(n, -1)
  if tonumber(digit) > 0 and tonumber(digit) <= 3 and string.sub(n,-2) ~= 11 and string.sub(n,-2) ~= 12 and string.sub(n,-2) ~= 13 then
    return n .. ordinal[tonumber(digit)]
  else
    return n .. "th"
  end
end
```

It could probably be made a bit better and cleaner, but it works for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your help! but there's one more thing.. Where do I exactly put this in? In the Lua File? and Is there anything I need to add before adding this particular code?

Comment: You would put it wherever you require it. If you're requiring a certain .lua file, then you could add it to that file. You can add it as is, and the way to use it would be something like `print(ordinal_numbers(34))` or whatever you're using to call it.

Comment: Please note that `string.sub` returns a string, and for 11-13 number exceptions to work, the compared values need to be strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function which returns the ordinal for a given day number:

```
function day_ordinal(dayn)
    last_digit = dayn % 10
    if last_digit == 1 and dayn ~= 11
        then return 'st'
    elseif last_digit == 2 and dayn ~= 12
        then return 'nd'
    elseif last_digit == 3 and dayn ~= 13
        then return 'rd'
    else 
        return 'th'
    end
end
```

This method doesn't require any string extractions/comparisons which is nice. You can then have a function which wraps `os.date` and 'extends' the functionality to allow for these ordinals to be inserted like so: (where `%o` inserts the ordinal of a date)

```
"Today is %A the %d%o"
```

A function which does this is as follows:

```
function timef(datestr,date)
    datestr = string.gsub(datestr,"%%o",day_ordinal(date.day))
    return os.date(datestr,os.time(datedate))
end
```

You can use this like follows:

```
date = os.date("*t",os.time())
print(timef("%A the %d%o",date))
```

Resulting in:

```
Sunday the 22nd
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this because I was looking for a solution to easily add ordinal indicators, however I needed something that can easily go further than just 31, so I just quickly threw something together and it seems to work (tested in loop until 410th) so I'm adding my code here in case anybody in the future comes across this.

```lua
function GetOrdinal(number)

    -- Creating necessary locals and tables
    local ordinal = ""
    local special_ordinals = {[1] = "st", [2] = "nd", [3] = "rd", [11] = "th", [12] = "th", [13] = "th"}
    local last_two = tonumber(string.sub(number, string.len(number) - 1))
    local last_one = tonumber(string.sub(number, string.len(number)))

    -- If last two / one digit(s) are / aren't on table
    if special_ordinals[last_two] then
        ordinal = special_ordinals[last_two]
    elseif special_ordinals[last_one] then
        ordinal = special_ordinals[last_one]
    else
        ordinal = "th"
    end

    -- Sending data back
    ordinal = number..ordinal
    return ordinal
end
```